# Find the area bounded by $y = \sin^3(x) + \cos^3(x)$ and $y = 0$ if $x \in [-\pi/4, 3\pi/4]$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, area

It took me hours to solve this. I had to split the given segment into three parts- $[-\pi/4, 0], [0, \pi/2], [\pi/2, 3\pi/4]$. Then I evaluated the definite integrals for $sin^3x$ and $cos^3x$ on each of these segments, then summed the pairs obtaining three values for the integrals on each of these segments for $sin^3x + cos^3x$ and finally summed the absolute values of these integrals getting $5\sqrt{2}/3$ which is the correct result. But this solution was way too long, resulting in frequent errors. Are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could note that the integrand is positive on the interval by the following:

$$\sin^3(x)+\cos^3(x) = \sin(x)\cdot(1-\cos^2(x))+\cos(x)\cdot(1-\sin^2(x))=(\sin(x)+\cos(x))\cdot(1-\sin(x)\cos(x))$$

The latter factor is always positive, while the first factor changes sign at the points where $\sin(x)=-\cos(x)$ which is at $n\pi-\frac \pi4$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

In the above equation it is easy to note that:
$$\sin(x)\cdot(1-\cos^2(x))+\cos(x)\cdot(1-\sin^2(x))
=\sin(x)+\cos(x)-\cos^2(x)\cdot\sin(x)-\sin^2(x)\cdot\cos(x)
=\frac d{dx}(-\cos(x))+\frac d{dx}\sin(x)+\frac d{dx}(\frac 13\cos^3(x))-\frac d{dx}(\frac 13\sin^3(x)).$$

This should immediately simplify your integration.